# Error: Could not find artifacts for ./mycontract from any sources

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration

The project is working on a Mac. Cloned from git on an Ubuntu machine while running `truffle migrate` it fails with: `Error: Could not find artifacts for ./mycontract from any sources.` Contract file of course exists, and code is working on the other box. What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this: `artifacts.require('MyContract')`.

Don't use the file name of the contract, use actual the name of the contract. `artifacts.require` uses the JSON files in `[project root]/build/contracts`, which are named after the contract's name, not it's file's name

Comment: great! it works, it will be nice to know why it does anyway on mac ...